# Gradle does not resolve "classified" library

Tags: java, gradle

I have two projects, `The_Base_Lib` and `The_Use_Case`. The_Base_Lib creates and publishes two artifacts to our organization-local repo:

```
The_Base_Lib-unspecified.jar
The_Base_Lib-unspecified-test.jar
```

The_Use_Case have dependencies on both the main and test parts of The_Base_Lib, like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile library(group: 'Foo', name: 'The_Base_Lib')
  testCompile library(group: 'Foo', name: 'The_Base_Lib', classifier: 'test')
}
```

When resolving, Gradle only downloads the `The_Base_Lib-unspecified.jar`, and not the test package.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is this `library` call doing?

Comment: Actually, it seems like it's just the "Gradle Runtime Dependencies" library in Eclipse that does not get updated. Need to understand what my question actually is, closing. :)